# Very specific cells in formulas that cannot change

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I am working on a spread sheet with cells that reference very specific cells and contain long formulas.  How can I get them to not change when a row or cell is added:
For example:
=MAX(G12+G13,G14+G15,G16+G17,G18+G19,G20+G21,G22+G23,G24+G25,G26+G27)

If I add a double row (as my table requires) it turns to:
=MAX(G14+G15,G16+G17,G18+G19,G20+G21,G22+G23,G24+G25,G26+G27,G28+G29)

Also for any answers can I use this when referencing from a different tab?
Like this:
=AVERAGE('Sheet1'!AE9:AG9,'Sheet1'!AE11:AG11,'Sheet1'!AE13:AG13,'Sheet1'!AE15:AG15)

Comment: Either use absolute reference ($G$12) or name reference name G12.

Comment: hmm I tried that but it came out:=MAX($D$14+$D$15,$D$16+$D$17,$D$18+$D$19,

Comment: sorry that should say:  I tried this but it came out:   =MAX($G$14+$G$15,$G$16+$G$17,$G$18+$G$19...

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent the cell references from changing, here are two methods of referring to cells that won't change the cell reference when you insert new rows:

1. Use the `INDIRECT` function:

   `=INDIRECT("G12") + INDIRECT("G13")`
2. Use the `INDEX` function

   `=INDEX(G:G,12,1) + INDEX(G:G,13,1)`

If you also need to retain the column G, even if other columns are inserted before Column G, again, you can use the `INDIRECT` method as noted above.

For the `INDEX` method, the formula would be:

```
=INDEX(A:G,12,7) + INDEX(A:G,13,7)
```

`INDIRECT` is somewhat easier to understand, but it is a volatile function.  `INDEX` is non-volatile in modern versions of Excel, so is preferred.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you Ron Rosenfeld.... so I tried: =MAX(INDIRECT(G12)+INDIRECT(G13),INDIRECT(G14)+INDIRECT(G15),INDIRECT(G16)+INDIRECT(G17)).... but I get #REF so I must have something typed wrong there....So I tried your =MAX((INDEX(G:G,12,1))+(INDEX(G:G,13,1)),(INDEX(G:G,14,1))+(INDEX(G:G,15,1))).....  and VOILA IT WORKED!!  Thank you so much!  I've worked on that much too long!